# git integrity problem

Tags: git

I wondered what happened if i mix git on linux with windows. Anyways i made a commit ("first") on linux, then modified a file on windows and committed there. It wouldnt let me because the end of line and patch seemed suspicious. So i tried from linux and it didnt allow me either...

I did `git reset --hard`. The files look like they have been resetted. However when i do git status it shows them all as modified. `git commit -a -m "test"` gets me the same problem. Git status shows them all modified. However `git clone .` creates a subdirectory and when i go there and write git status none of them are showed modified.

Even if its a timestamp problem why cant i recommit it and whats with the errors? Right now the simple solution would to move the current directory out and do a fresh clone on it. But i'd like to understand the problem going on.

Comment: what's the output of `git config --get core.autocrlf` in the mentioned directory?

Comment: @Idan K: true. That might have been my fault as i used tortiousegit and changed a few options, that was one of them. But still shouldnt that work?

Comment: @Idan K: I dont know if core.autocrlf should be that value or not. What were you saying?

Comment: I'm not sure it's such a good idea to have `autocrlf` on if you're sharing a working directory between Windows and Linux (since Git checks out files on Windows with CRLF EOL and on Linux with LF). Since you use the same working dir, I'm thinking it might confuse Git. Try turning it off, repeat your experiments and then report back the result.

Comment: @Idan K: I tried and played around again. --no-verify is interesting but the other answer i saw on SO and answers found by google didnt really work. the --no-verify i could force it but i dont think its a good idea to do everytime. So i'll just conclude my test with, no it doesnt work well. Although it does seem the actual repository can be read perfectly fine by windows and linux. Maybe tortiousegit is wrecking something but i DOUBT that. I wanted to try msysgit git bash but it didnt allow me to visit unc paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this exactly answers your question, but I'm using git (with svn as a backend, hosted on linux) on windows, and my colleagues are using git on a mac. I'm using [git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) as my windows git client, and it tells me when it is altering the default line endings added by windows. We haven't encountered any conflicts concerning line endings at all. In "Global settings" and "Local settings" I haven't specified anthing about how to handle line endings, so it looks as though the default behaviour is taking care of it all.